# Running .vbs scipt inside Python doesn't do anything

Tags: python, vbscript, automation

**Idea**

Basically, what my script does is checking C:/SOURCE for .txt files and add a timestamp to it. To replicate it you can basically make that folder and put some txt files in there. Then, it's supposed to run a .vbs file, which then runs a .bat files with some rclone commands which don't matter here. I did it like this because there wont be a CMD window opening when running the rclone command through the .vbs file.

**Python code**

```python
import time, os, subprocess

while True:
    print("Beginning checkup")
    print("=================")
    timestamp = time.strftime('%d_%m_%H_%M')  # only underscores: no naming issues
    the_dir = "C:/SOURCE"
    for fname in os.listdir(the_dir):
        if fname.lower().endswith(".txt"):
            print("found " + fname)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            new_name = "{}-{}.txt".format(os.path.splitext(fname)[0], timestamp)
            os.rename(os.path.join(the_dir, fname), os.path.join(the_dir, new_name))
            time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        subprocess.call(['cscript.exe', "copy.vbs"])
        time.sleep(60)
```

**VBScript code**

```vb
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run Chr(34) & "copy.bat" & Chr(34), 0 
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

The only important part for the Python script is below the very last `else`, where the `subprocess.call()` is supposed to run the .vbs file. What happens when running the script is it shows the first two lines that always come up when running CMD, but then nothing.

How could I fix that? I tried:

```python
subprocess.call("cscript copy.vbs")
subprocess.call("cmd /c copy.vbs")
```

both with the same outcome, it doesn't do anything.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you invoking a VBScript to invoke a batch script from Python? You should be able to simple run whatever the batch script is doing directly from your Python code. But even if you wanted to keep the batch script, something like this should do just fine without VBScript as an intermediary.

```py
subprocess.call(['cmd', '/c', 'copy.bat'])
```

You may want to give the full path of the batch file, though, to avoid issues like the working directory not being what you think it is.

If your batch script resides in the same directory as the Python script, you can build the path with something like this:

```py
import os
import subprocess

scriptdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
batchfile = os.path.join(scriptdir, 'copy.bat')

subprocess.call(['cmd', '/c', os.path.realpath(batchfile)])
```

Comment: I would do that, if it didnt open up a cmd windows. The whole point of putting a vbs file inbetween is to make it not visible to the user. Thats what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Oh you're right. The whole point of the .bat and .vbs file is to make it invisible from the user but it seems to be possible directly from python. Thanks for the insight, really didnt think about that!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no such an operation that could not be done using plain Python. Scan a directory, copy a file -- Python has it all in the standard library. See `os.path` and `shutil` modules.

Adding VB scripts and launching subprocesses make your code complex and difficult to debug.

Comment: rclone is needed to upload files to the cloud so I have to use it.

Comment: Since you really need to use COM objects, try to use great win32 library: see this link: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html